AKS addon: azure-keyvault-secrets-provider is unable to sync k8s secret
1)We have enabled addons for azure keyvault by issuing below command on AKS:
az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider --name CLUSTER-NAME --resource-group RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME


Then,we have created secret provider class with 2 secret objects.
Once the pod that uses the above spc came up, it has created a k8s secret.

now,
I have added few more secretobjects in the above SPC
but, the pod is unable to come up as it is looking for the new secret objects. Also, the k8s secret is not updated with new secret objects(i.e., not syncd).
However, If I manually delete the k8s secret, then a new k8s secret with all the secretobjects came up and things went fine.
How I can avoid this manual step and enable the syncsecret?

You need to set up syncSecret to true in your SecretProviderClass:
spec:
  syncSecret:
    enabled: true

And the re-apply this yaml:
kubectl apply -f <your-yaml-filename>


strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.syncSecret"

Please provide the whole yaml file

You didn't enable secret rotation when you enable the driver. You can still enable it with:
az aks addon update \
  --resource-group RESOURCE-GROUP-NAME \
  --name CLUSTER-NAME \
  --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider \
  --enable-secret-rotation

